# How I can do this query in MySQL (multiple columns from different tables)

Tags: mysql

I want to select 3 columns from different tables but I must to use functions, this is the query that I want to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.sum(column1) as sumcol1,
      table2.sum(column2) as sumcol2, table3.column3 as col3 
 FROM db1.table1, db1.table2, db1.table3 
WHERE table1.id = 1  AND table2.id = 1 AND table3.id = 1;
```

note: only table3.id is unique index

and I want to get this table:

```
 |sumcol1|sumcol2|col3|
 |1234556|5432113|432|
```

Comment: you should look up JOIN syntax and use that. it will help you alot with how you lay out your selects and should prevent improper queries

Comment: I do not think that's the solution, the problem is the function "sum" inside the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not mentioned the logic. Looks like missplaced `SUM`

```
SELECT DISTINCT sum(table1.column1) as sumcol1,
          sum(table2.column2) as sumcol2, table3.column3 as col3 
     FROM db1.table1, db1.table2, db1.table3 
    WHERE table1.id = 1  AND table2.id = 1 AND table3.id = 1;
```

Comment: hehe you found the answer before me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was simple.

> SELECT DISTINCT sum(table1.column1) as sumcol1, sum(table2.column2) as sumcol2, table3.column3 as col3 FROM db1.table1, db1.table2, db1.table3 WHERE table1.id = 1 AND table2.id = 1 AND table3.id = 1;

I just change table1.sum(column1) for sum(table1.column1) and i change table2.sum(column2) for sum(table2.column2)